# Shopify add coupon in order note

Tags: php, shopify, liquid

It seems this is where I can parse information to the notes section of an order:

```
{{ cart.note }}
```

This was my code to try and add the discount code to the cart note:

```
{% for discount in discounts %}
discount.code = {{ cart.note }}
{% endfor %}
```

Can anyone please tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: A customer enters their discount code at Step 2 of the Shopify checkout. The cart.note has already been entered at that point (on the cart page) and cannot be added too. What exactly are you trying to do and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with what you're trying to do here.

1. The `discounts` variable is part of an [`order`](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-variables/order), and does not exist yet on the Cart page (discounts are added by the customer during the checkout process).
2. `cart.note` is created by having an input element with `name="note"` inside the form on the Cart page, and the value of that element becomes the order's `note`. [See here for more info](http://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/ask-customer-for-more-information).

Also, from the [Shopify wiki about `cart.note`](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-variables/cart):

> Adds a note field to your checkout template... The general idea is that you simply define an input field named "note" in the form that submits to "/cart" in cart.liquid.

Where are you putting your code?

`order.note` may be editable via the [API](http://docs.shopify.com/api/order), but I haven't tried this so I'm not sure.